# call a class from a second jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm using NetBeans 8.1. Trying to use a class from a second jar.

in the utility.jar I have a public class declared:

```
public class myclass {
    // does Stuff     
}
```

it is showing up in the IDE under: 
myproject\source packages\myproject\myclass.jar\myclass.class

in myproject.jar I have:

```
package myproject;
import myclass.*;
```

ERROR: package myclass does not exist unused import

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not wrong about your Package and it's name is `utility.jar`and `myClass` is indeed a class in it than you can import it this way:

```
import utility.myclass ;
```

This is how you generally import a class from package:

```
import packageName.className;
```

Note a package Name can take different formats like this : `org.example`

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are doing wrong is you are not mentioning the package name when trying to import that class.
Try to mention the package name in your `import` statement.

I am not sure coz i actually didn't understood your question properly but you can try this and see if it works.